# Sort & Dist keys selection for a dimension table in Redshift database

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift database, I want to decide a sort key for a dimension table  between surrogatekey and natural primary key. The definition says "Sort keys should be selected based on the most commonly used columns when filtering, ordering or grouping the data". 
My Question is -

I have a Employee table with (Emp_key,Emp_Id,Emp_name) and this table is joined to Fact table on Emp key. Here "Emp_key" is the surrogate key and "Emp_id" is the natural primary key. And I filter the query on Emp_id but "Emp_key" in the fact table is defined as a "dist key" and read that for a large dimension defining sort & dist keys on the join keys results in better performance and so I want to know which one should i choose between Emp_key and Emp_id for Sort key in a dimension table?

And also, another confusion is choosing sort for the "date" dimension table between "date_key" or ignore defining sort key.

I would appreciate your suggestions in this regard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your employee table likely doesn't contain too many rows, you can choose `ALL` distribution style, so the copy of the table sits on every node of your cluster. This way you'll avoid this dilemma at a very low cost.

UPD: with this design, I would have emp_key as dist key (so that data that is joined sits on the same nodes) and emp_id as sort key (to filter efficiently). I'm pretty sure the query planner would prioritize filtering over joining, so first it will filter the rows from the dimension table and only then it will join the corresponding rows from the fact table. But it's better to try all options and benchmark a few queries to see what works best.

If you can change the design I would just add emp_id to the fact table (because it seems like the keys map 1 to 1) as a part of ELT and avoid the dilemma again.

Comment: Thank you for the response Alex! Employee table is just an example I have provided. But I have a large dimension table and want to know which key to choose as Sort key between surrogate key and natural primary key. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alex for the clarification! that helps! Can you suggest the best sort & Dist styles for "Date" dimension? Thank you!

Comment: It's a date dimension and is joined to fact table on "date_key".

Comment: @varun yes but what is the benefit of having a separate key instead of using the date column itself as a key?

Comment: date_key here is a surrogate key, which is in integer format rather than using the date as is. It's a typical star schema design.

Comment: @varun I know. But my understanding is that surrogate key is used in addition to the natural key when there is more than one row with the same natural key in your table. This is not the case for the date table because there will be only one row per one date with its attributes. The nature of this data is that it doesn't have any versions/states. That's why I'm asking if there is any other benefit of following this pattern.

Comment: This key has the date value in the integer format and derived from date. ForEg: date_key=20190410 where as the date field has the same value in the date format. as per my knowledge joins between fact and dimension table are better with fields of integer type. So, my date dimension table has the format (date_key,date,month,year,..)(20190410, 04-10-2019 00:00:00,April,2019,.) And I wanted to know if I have to choose sort key on the filed "date_key" or "date" or ignore defining it altogether because all fields from this table are possible to create filters (including month & year fields). Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's better to join by date type field if it is sorted in both fact and dimension table, versus joining by an integer field if it is not sorted. Just have one field and sort it :) Anyway, you can benchmark both options by creating tables with both designs and running queries